# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helper' . No unique bean of type [java.lang.String]

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I want to autowire a string to constructor.

I have this in the spring config xml:

```
<bean id="helper" class="test.Helper">
    <constructor-arg index="3" type="java.lang.String" value="http://test.com" />  
</bean>
```

Helper.java

```
@Component
public class Helper {
    private final ClientFactory clientFactory;
    private final ModelManager modelManager;
    private final SecurityService securityService;
    private final String url;

    @Autowired
    public Helper(ClientFactory clientFactory, ModelManager modelManager,
        SecurityService securityService, String url) {
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
        this.modelManager = modelManager;
        this.securityService = securityService;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

I am getting error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [java.lang.String] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 19:

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have a few conflicts here. Your `Helper` class is a `@Component`, but you also have a `bean` declared for it. You would end up with two instances of the `Helper` class in your context.

Comment: I am noob with springs. So how to inject only url for Helper? Other params are also components. I tried using                           <bean id="url" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg><value>"http://test"</value></constructor-arg>
    </bean>. Even that didn't work! Should I use @Qualifier in constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Try Droping the `@Autowired` annotation in Ctor and configuring it in xml:

```
<bean id="helper" class="test.Helper">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientFactory" />  
    <constructor-arg ref="modelManager" />  
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="http://test.com" />  
    <constructor-arg ref="securityService" />  
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use index attribute along with constructor dependencies.

```
<bean id="helper" class="test.Helper">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="clientFactory" />  
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="modelManager" />  
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="securityService" />  
    <constructor-arg index="3" type="java.lang.String" value="http://test.com" />  
</bean>
```

This should help.